# How do I do this Text animation in Sony Vegas (..or AE)?

Tags: after-effects, animation, vegas-pro

Sometimes, when I have a look at music videos, I see lyric texts coming up. They are shaped in a rectangle, with different sized words. An example is this, which I made quickly.
[image]

What is this effect called?

Let's say I have a music video. And I want to add lyrics to it, just like the example. How would I do this, animated, showing one by one in Sony Vegas Pro 13, or Adobe After Effects (Preferably Sony Vegas, I at used to the controls more)?

Comment: How is it exactly related?

Comment: Sony Vegas was not designed for such tasks, you have to use AE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Kinetic Type](http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/10-free-after-effects-templates-typography/) generally (that link is for Templates). Depending on what you're looking to do you either need to do it manually or can use scripting to auto-fill a list of words. If you auto-fill with a list its generally more randomized, so if sequence is important. Like you want the Lyrics to appear in the order they're spoken you must do it manually.

You can use After Effects or Flash to create something like this.

- [Tools to help make Kinetic Typography](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/is-there-any-plugin-for-after-effects-to-create-a-kinetic-typography-video) (Video Stack Exchange for After Effects)
- [Using a Script to do it automatically with random words](http://levitated.net/daily/levEmotionFractal.html) (Levitated.net for Flash)